# Limit a function to once per IP address without user logins

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a site that allows you to post comments to a page and vote on other comments, except it's all anonymous, there are no user logins whatsoever.

I already have a comment rating system in place, but currently there's nothing stopping someone from just repeatedly rating a comment to their heart's content.

I need to make it so once you vote, that's it. You can't go back on it, and you can't vote on that same post again.

Here's an example, my rateup.php file:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$post_id = $_GET['id'];

// Connection to database
$connection=mysqli_connect("$servername","$username","$password","$dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'oops';
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Increasing the current value with 1

mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE $tablename SET upvotes = (upvotes + 1) WHERE id = $post_id");
mysqli_close($connection);

echo 'done';   ?>
```

Honestly, I had a hard time even thinking of how to explain this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: My guess is you will need to keep the votes record in a separate table with a column where you will need to store the ip address (user used to vote for). and then you should allow only one vote from one ip for one post.

Example:
post_id | vote | ip
1 | 1 | 108.1.1.1
1 | 1 | 108.1.2.1

Comment: If theirs no login, how does it keep track of who's who?

Comment: It doesn't really have to, it's supposed to be anonymous. I'm still logging IPs but only for this purpose, and they'll be deleted when the posts are purged.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in one of my projects.

Make a table this way :-

```
comment_id IP
```

Now in this table, store the "upvotes". So suppose if a use with ip `127.0.0.1` upvotes comment with comment ID `456`, then add a row for it.

Now, bind an ajax request with every click(the upvote button), as soon as someone clicks to do an "upvote", the requests goes to an ajax handler page with the comment id. On this page, grab the user's IP and query using this data to see if you have a record or not.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total from table where comment_id = ? AND IP = ?
```

If `total` is **1**, it means user is trying to make a second vote, if not, the vote is legit and you proceed.

Comment: Alright, I didn't think of storing those IPs in a separate table. I am going to try a few things with this and I'll let you know. I'm pretty new to PHP and MySQL and this is the first project I'm attempting alone.

Comment: This is really very easy. Give it a try, you can always ask SO for help!

Comment: How can I format this as an if statement? I'm assuming I have to put this into my rateup.php file, so I'd want to check if their IP has already voted on that post, and if they haven't, rate it up and add them to the table.

Comment: @Treedot
I'd suggest you to make a function for it. Something like `function hasRated($comment_id, $user_ip)`. Here, check the data against the table and let this function return `1` if there already exists an entry, and `0` if there's no entry.
Now your if would look like :- `if(hasRated($comment_id, $user_ip) == 0)
{ // user has not rated, proceed}
else
{//user already rated}`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Is it really as simple as that? I don't need to pull any data from the IP table or anything?

Comment: I mean, how do I tell it which table to pull from?

Comment: @Treedot
The function `hasRated()` does that. Check my answer with the SQL code.

Comment: Yup, I figured it all out, thank you. However, I've come to the conclusion that because there's no user ID system, there's no real way to stop someone from voting as many times as they want, so I'm most likely removing voting all together. I've just set it aside for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the user IP and browser fingerprint information in your database tables, instead of usernames who added/modified the content. So for instance if you have upvotes table, your schema be something like:

```
commentid, text, creation_date, created_by
```

Where created_by field is IP address of the user. Also you can store few other variables from the $_REQUEST which may help you uniquely identify the visitor.

All of these measures are not fool-proof as usually users sit behind dynamic IPs and NAT firewalls, so their IP may change very frequently.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table to save your IP address for each vote:

```
CREATE TABLE IP_post_votes (
    post_id INT
    ip varchar(15)
);
```

Now, whenever you update your upvote table, you should check for ips in the IP_post_votes table, and insert if not exists, in a transaction. Also, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause will give best performance than one query for count data and another to update data:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($connection);
mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE $tablename SET upvotes = (upvotes + 1) WHERE id = $post_id AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM IP_post_votes where IP = $ip and post_id = $post_id)");

if(mysqli_affected_rows() > 0) {
    $insert = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO IP_post_votes values($post_id, $ip)");
    $insert ? 
        mysqli_commit($connection):
        mysqli_rollback($connection);
} else {
    mysqli_rollback($connection);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this now because I couldn't make the above answers work, i'm getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_begin_transaction()`

Comment: Oh shoot, it's probably because `mysql_begin_transaction()` doesn't exist until PHP 5.5 and I am running 5.2, and have no way to change that. Is there a workaround?